# Why does script output blanks at certain rows?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator, python-parser, arcgis-10.6

I have been trying to run a script, which runs successfully. However, when using the select by attribute tool and choosing get unique values, I have noticed there are certain rows that do not produce the output as stated in the script but rather output blanks

[image].

Any idea why it is doing so?

The script I am using is as follows:

```
def Reclass (HU_OctNovDe):
    if HU_OctNovDe >= 600:
      return "Optimal"
    elif HU_OctNovDe < 600:
      return "Suboptimal"
    else:
      return "N/A"
```

[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot showing rows where it doesnt work

Comment: What are the HU_OctNovDe values for the row that get empty value as a result ? is it always the same value ?

Comment: How do you call the function? You cant calculate two fields at once

Comment: I have added the screenshot showing the blanks. There are values which meet the command but there is a blank for some odd reason

Comment: Expression used : Reclass (!HU_OctNovDe!)

Comment: Have you tried sorting your field OctDec_Hu? I suspect you have rows with no values hence the blank values ''?

Comment: I have sorted the fields, there are values, yet the output is blank

Comment: Are you sure you are calling it with `OctDec_HU = Reclass (!HU_OctNovDe!)` and not `JanMar_HU = Reclass (!HU_OctNovDe!)`

Comment: Yes I am sure, I rechecked.

Comment: Did you have a selection on the table? Because the field calculator will only calculate values for selected records

Comment: No selection was on the table when running the script

Comment: With 1.5M+ records in the table it could be the memory cache being a bit slow to catch up?  I'd also consider using pandas and/or numpy to do these sort of calculations on large datasets.  I've found Select By Attributes to be a bit unreliable when the record count is beyond a few hundred thousand.  You could also use MakeFeatureLayer with a where statement to select the records.

Comment: Hi Dan, many thanks for the comment. It definitely was the memory. I removed some unnecessary columns of data from the table and re-ran the script and it worked!!!!